# Python Subtracting two columns with date data, from csv to get number of weeks , months?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv in which I have two columns representing start date: `st_dt` and end date: 'end_dt` , I have to subtract these columns to get the number of weeks. I tried iterating through columns using pandas, but it seems my output is wrong.

```
 st_dt                 end_dt
---------------------------------------
20100315           20100431
```

Comment: show us what you tried and what's the output you getting? Also provide expected output.

Comment: This is what i am coding,   for idx, date in data.iterrows():    
        data['expdate'] =  datetime.strptime( str(date['exdate']), '%Y%m%d') - datetime.strptime( str(date['date']), '%Y%m%d')  after this how can i update the my results in CSV file

Comment: @Quant - what is expected output from your input?

Comment: expected output should be in number of days, which i can convert into weeks or months . Please note i have thousand of dates in csv.

Comment: @Quant - `20100431` does not exist, only `20100430`  it is typo?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with `parse_dates` for datetimes and then after substract [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=[0,1])
print (df)
       st_dt     end_dt
0 2010-03-15 2010-04-30

df['diff'] = (df['end_dt'] - df['st_dt']).dt.days
print (df)
       st_dt     end_dt  diff
0 2010-03-15 2010-04-30    46
```

If some dates are wrong like `20100431` use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaT`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
print (df)
      st_dt    end_dt
0  20100315  20100431
1  20100315  20100430

df['st_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['st_dt'], errors='coerce', format='%Y%m%d')
df['end_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_dt'], errors='coerce', format='%Y%m%d')

df['diff'] = (df['end_dt'] - df['st_dt']).dt.days
print (df)
       st_dt     end_dt  diff
0 2010-03-15        NaT   NaN
1 2010-03-15 2010-04-30  46.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is the way i am doing , because the values from CSV are in raw format i think we cannot directly use dt.days    values = []     
    for idx, date in data.iterrows():
        result =  datetime.strptime( str(date['exdate']), '%Y%m%d') - datetime.strptime( str(date['date']), '%Y%m%d')
        values.append(result)

Comment: Yes, the best not  use it, because `iterrows` very slow.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316)